# HashMap for noobs - compilator "cannot find symbol - method get(java.lang.string)"

Tags: java, hashmap

I can't find a solution on this by myself. Please give me a tip or something

```
import java.util.*;


       import java.io.*;

        class Fulgleinfluens {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap <String, Komm> Komm = new hashMap<String, Komm>();

        int teller = 0;

         try {
         Scanner FilKom = new Scanner(new File("KommuneKoordinater.txt"));

         while(FilKom.hasNextLine()) {
      String linje = FilKom.nextLine();
      String [] dellinje = linje.split(",");
      String kommune = dellinje[0];
      String fylke = dellinje[1];
      String lengdegrad = dellinje[2];
      String breddegrad = dellinje[3];

      Komm enKom = new Komm(kommune, fylke, lengdegrad, breddegrad);
      Komm.put(kommune, enKom);
      teller++;

         }
     } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("En feil oppsto ved lesing av fil");
     }
     System.out.println("Lest "+teller+" antall linjer");
        }

        void getKommuneMap () {
     String kommune = "Sarpsborg";
     Komm enKom = (Komm) Komm.get(kommune);
        }
        }

        class Komm {
        String kommune;
        String fylke;
        String lengdegrad;
        String breddegrad;

        Komm(String kommune, String fylke, String lengdegrad, String breddegrad) {
             this.kommune = kommune;
             this.fylke = fylke;
             this.lengdegrad = lengdegrad;
             this.breddegrad = breddegrad;
        }
        }
```

Comment: This can't be your code. It's full of spelling mistakes, like hashMap for HashMap. I can't tell where in the code you are getting the error in your subject.

Answer (score 1):

You can't name an instance of your map the same as the name of the class `Komm`.  Change it to `komm` and it should be ok.  Right now you are trying to call a static method on `Komm` rather than `HashMap.get()`.

Comment: `komm` is a terrible name for anything that's not an instance of `Komm`. Maybe call it `kommMap` or something. I don't know what Komm means so I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. But I really don't think a variable should be named `komm` if it's not referring to a `Komm`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm new to programming(java) and learning, thanks for alle the answares. When changing the HashMap name to komm, the compilator cant find variabel komm in 

Komm enKom = (Komm) komm.get(kommune);

Comment: @MatrixFrog - you're right, I got confused between the types.  `kommMap` is a better choice.

Comment: @cbeberge - how did you change the name?  Please post your updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Are your imports correct? Try :

```
import java.util.*;  // or java.util.HashMap 
import java.io.*;
```

I see the imports corrected. But your code is messed up. Your `Komm` variable is defined so many times.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call `Komm.get()` which will only work if `get()` is defined as a static method in the class `Komm`. As far as I can tell, it's not.